# IntelliJ: After creating Artifacts and exporting project as .jar, the jar does nothing, even when opend by cmd.exe

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just have one blank line and then it gives me my commandprompt back. There is no sign of my code at all... Whats happening? Any help?

Comment: Try tu run "java -jar your_file.jar"

Comment: I am on Windows, on Linux you would be correct.

Comment: It's the same on Windows too

Comment: @FABULATOR Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify how you run it and what you expect to see.